# Добавление и обнвление информации в словарь

Tags: python, словари, for, dict, tuple

Есть следующий код:

```
pets = [('Hatiko', 'Parker', 'Wilson', 50),
        ('Rusty', 'Josh', 'King', 25),
        ('Fido', 'John', 'Smith', 28),
        ('Butch', 'Jake', 'Smirnoff', 18),
        ('Odi', 'Emma', 'Wright', 18),
        ('Balto', 'Josh', 'King', 25),
        ('Barry', 'Josh', 'King', 25),
        ('Snape', 'Hannah', 'Taylor', 40)]

def dog_owners(data_list):
    result = {}
    for [*element] in data_list:
        key = (element[1], element[2], element[3])
        value = element[0]
        if result[key] not in result.keys():
            result[key] = value
        else:
            result.update({key: value})
    print(result)
    
dog_owners(pets)
```

Как реализовать добавление новых элементов в словарь, в которых ключ это кортеж из имени, фамилии и возраста хозяина, а значение это кличка собаки (если у хозяина несколько собак, то они быть перечислены через запятую)?

На данный момент мой код (см. выше) выдает ошибку `KeyError`, хотя не не понимаю почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так будет работать:

```
def dog_owners(data_list):
    result = {}
    for value,*key in data_list:
        key = tuple(key)
        if key not in result:
            result[key] = [value]
        else:
            result[key].append(value)
    print(result)

dog_owners(pets)
```

- Можно не мучиться с индексами, а сразу сделать распаковку/упаковку нужных позиций в `key` и `value`.
- Проверка на вхождение ключа в словарь делается через `<key> in <dict>` и `.keys()` можно при этом не писать.
- Чтобы получить список значений в одном элементе словаря, нужно держать и пополнять именно список в качестве значения.